# MongoDB not starting, reports error with SSL certificate that is not yet expired

Tags: database, mongodb, ssl, certbot

Error from MongoDB logs:

2022-07-30T05:18:05.262+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2022-07-30T05:18:05.344+0000 F  NETWORK  [main] The provided SSL certificate is expired or not yet valid.
2022-07-30T05:18:05.344+0000 F  -        [main] Fatal Assertion 28652 at src/mongo/util/net/ssl_manager_openssl.cpp 1182
2022-07-30T05:18:05.344+0000 F  -        [main] \n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n

However, according to certbot, the SSL certificate we are using is not expired. It is still valid and does not need to be renewed at the moment.

All MongoD service just stopped working and cannot access the admin website.

The service won't restart as well on the server which is running:

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
MongoDB v4.2.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least four possibilities:

1. You are using a different certificate than the one certbot is testing.
2. The certificate has not expired but the date on your system is wrong.
3. The certificate has expired or one in the certificate chain has expired.
4. The certificate was issued for a future date.

Use openssl to display the servers' certificate details:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect hostname:27017 | openssl x509 -text
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have resolved the problem. I deleted the PEM file and then just recreated it again using the existing fullchain.pem and privkey.pem files.